# How do your scroll through autocomplete suggestions in cloud 9 ide?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Is there a way in cloud 9 ide to scroll through the autocomplete suggestions without using arrow keys? Read through key bindings but might be missing something. Really sucks having to take hands away from home row keys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do that, but code that handles up down arrows is at https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.language/blob/77f75c7635584656d9da805d049d4866b5bdee6b/complete.js#L682-L695, so should be easy to convert to a command with configurable keybinding